# Remove used engine oil stain from running shoes

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I have a pair of Adidas Los Angeles Denim running shoes the same as [these](http://www.adidas.co.uk/los-angeles-shoes-denim-pack/S78367.html?prefn1=sizeSearchValue&prefv1=).  Apparently they have a denim upper which is printed with a pattern.

Over the weekend I was changing the oil on my car and mistakenly caught and kicked over the container with the used engine oil in it.  I got a smallish amount of oil on the toe of my shoe.  I instantly put my shoes in our washing machine using non-bio detergent (our machine has a "shoe" program) and the result was reasonably acceptable.  The white rubber area of the sole is almost spotless.  On the toe area there is still a slight discoloring / dullness.

Is this staining something I'm just going to have to live with or can anyone suggest anything or any process that might remove this stain from the printed denim?

Comment: Have you checked ["remove engine oil stains from clothes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+engine+oil+stains+from+clothes)? For example, there are 4 methods in the first result: http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Grease-or-Oil-Stains-from-Clothing. If you've already given them the elbow grease then unfortunately you just have to live with it; used motor oil has more than just oil in it. Next time you buy new shoes keep these ones, that way when you do work you'll have not-your-nicest-pair-of-shoes to wear while you do it. Lesson: Don't wear nice clothes when doing dirty work.

Answer (score 2):

Orange hand cleaner (without pumice) from the auto parts store, walmart, etc. 
Works on clothes, might work on your shoes.

Comment: If this is what I'm thinking of,  it may also go by the name of Orange oil - in Australia, at least.  Though this won't help the OP, it may help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

1. Lather with Goo Goo Gone.
2. Brush with a soft bristle brush,
3. Wipe with suede rag, damp with nail polish remover (flammable!)l
4. Air dry.

*Never* machine wash sneakers!

Answer (score 1):

Use Greased Lightning. I used to get oil in my clothes growing up and this would get it out every time.

```
http://www.greased-lightning.com/Laundry/
```

"Athletic Shoes

Just spray Greased Lightning directly to your shoe’s soiled area and wipe clean. For set-in stains, scrub with a well-bristled brush and toss into the washer. Test in an inconspicuous area first."

Answer (score 1):

Any time I get oil or other difficult to remove stains on my clothes I use washing up liquid (or dish soap) to remove them. The soap in the washing up liquid breaks down the oil and makes it easier to remove.

Try using a bit of soap massaged into the stain with a soft bristled toothbrush. The apply a but more soap, leave to soak for a few minutes and wash the shoe in your washing machine again.

It should get rid of the stain for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if it's a grease stain from oil or a blackening stain from the byproducts of combustion (the spot that engine oil accumulates turning it black. A picture would be helpful. If a grease stain I would have advocated using gasoline on a clean rag as a solvent to soak into the stain and spread it out/transfer the majority percentage to the tag so that it becomes imperceptible. If it's a soot stain a more rigorous soaping combined with a forceful rinse.

I'd also recommend next time placing your feet into plastic bags and tying them up to protect the top of your shoes and/or perhaps putting some old sports socks on over your shoes

Answer (score -1):

Shout Advanced Aerosol Spray,gets out even dried in motor oil, or any kind of oil. You could also try Dawn dishwashing liquid. I know for a fact it gets out dried in cooking grease and I have tried it on motor oil,but I think I had to wash it more than once, I can't remember. The trick to getting any kind of oil out is to wash it before it gets dry, I know sometimes that isn't possible,but pre-wash with Dawn and then use the Shout Advanced.